# loop doesn't iterate over all the csv file read, python2, pycharm

Tags: python-2.7, loops, csv

here is my code:

```
import csv
inp1 = raw_input('Enter your Hijjri year:')
intinp1 = int(inp1)
majmouaopen = open('Majmoua.csv')
majmouaread = csv.reader(majmouaopen)
majmouaread.next()
mabsoutaopen = open('Mabsouta.csv')
mabsoutaread = csv.reader(mabsoutaopen)
mabsoutaread.next()
hijrimiladimonthsopened = open('MiladiHijrimonths.csv')
hijrimiladimonthsread = csv.reader(hijrimiladimonthsopened)
yearslist = []     
years = []
yearssection = []
monthssection = []
minutessection = []
def miladifromhijri(intinp1):#, inp2, intinp3):
    fulyear = intinp1 - 1
    n = 0
    for row in majmouaread:
        print row
        introw = int(row[0])
        if introw <= fulyear:
            n += 1
            years.append(introw)
            continue
        if n == len(years):
            near = years[::-1][0]
            nearlessyear = near
        break
    for row in majmouaread:
        print row
```

my problem is with the last loop, it doesn't print all of the majmouaread files. for  the first loop, which is the same, it does print all of the csv file rows.
What is causing the probblem, is it something in the code? or something happened to the csv file read? It looks fine with first loop?

Comment: Ok,Thanks there it is now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I repeat the 'for' loop for csv.Reader? (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150155/why-cant-i-repeat-the-for-loop-for-csv-reader-python)

Comment: As explained in the duplicate question, once an iterator has read a row, it won't go back and read it again.  To loop through the rows of your input file a second time, you'll need a second iterator.  The [selected answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367594#31367642) offers some alternative solutions that I think are more clear than the first question's answer.

Comment: I tried another iterator, and it doesn't work

Comment: ok, the seek func helped :D

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific enough.  The file object created with `open` _also_ keeps track of "where it is", so just creating a new `csv.reader` iterator won't help, because the file is (presumably) also at the end.  File objects, while _iterable_, are not iterators --- you _can_ tell them to "rewind" with the `seek(0)` method, as in the answer to the first question.  I find that to be kind of sneaky, and prefer to `close` and re-`open` the file, then create a new `csv.reader`, as in the second question.  Or, if there's not much data, read it all into a big list (both answers suggest that).

Comment: Thanks, just it works fine with csv.seek(0).