# "why can't I use the Python "in" operator to tell if a word is present in a CSV file?"

Tags: python

I'm  spliting a string into words and for each word I'm going through each row of a CSV file to check if this word exists in any row or not. If it exists I want to print this row

```
import csv
tempfile = open("word.csv",'r')

listtext = csv.reader(tempfile)

sti = "this is not a very good string"

sss =  sti.split(" ")

print sss

for word in sss:
    print word
    for x in listtext:
        if str(word) in x:
            print x
```

This is the output I'm getting

```
['this', 'is', 'not', 'a', 'very', 'good', 'string']

this

is

not

a

very

good

string
```

This is the output I want

```
['proud', 'flesh', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'n', '-0.38925']
['proud', 'of', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'a', '-0.03118']
['proud', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'a', '0.5']
['tarquin', 'the', 'proud', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'n', '-0.07997']
```

I'm getting this output with this code

```
for x in list-text:
    if "proud" in x:
        print x
```

Comment: ...and? How does this output differ from what you expect it to be, and *why* do you expect what you do? (ie. for someone who reads the code and thinks the output is exactly what it should be, can you explain why there's a question/problem here?)

Comment: we don't know your content of the csv... do we?

Comment: I'd also suggest making your question's code self-contained -- right now, someone can't test it themselves without a copy of `word.csv`.

Comment: ...BTW, as a rule, a title should be specific enough that it can't apply to anyone else's problem but yours -- probably 50% of all questions on the site could use the title "why is this code not working as it's supposed to?", which makes it worthless at letting someone tell if they have the same problem (and thus whether the answers to your problem might be applicable to them as well); if instead your question were, for example, *"why can't I use the Python "in" operator to tell if a word is present in a CSV file?"*, that would be specific and helpful at conveying intent.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for suggesting. Changing it.

Comment: Editing in the relevant contents of `word.csv` would still be helpful.

Comment: But the same word.csv is working this "proud". why is it not working with string array ?

Comment: If my theory is correct, btw, then this is a duplicate of [Why can't I repeat the 'for' loop for csv.Reader?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150155/why-cant-i-repeat-the-for-loop-for-csv-reader-python)

Comment: Wait a second. Why didn't you post an example csv file again? I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

A CSV reader is a *generator* in Python: It yields lines whenever asked for its next item, until all those lines have been consumed. Once they've been consumed, it's done and has no more content: You can't run that same generator through a loop a second time and get more results from it.

However, by iterating first over your list of words to match, and *then* against the contents of the CSV file, you're trying to do exactly that -- with the effect that the CSV file will be read only once, matched against the first word in your string ("this"), but not any other.

If you want to create an object you can iterate through more than once, you'll want something like:

```
listtext = list(csv.reader(tempfile))
```

**Or** you can invert your loop: iterating first over lines of the input file, and *then* against lines you want to match against it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem as answered by Charles is that once you've spun through the csv with `for x in listtext:`, the csv row reader has been exhausted and there is nothing left to process the next time through the outer loop.

Any time you find yourself spinning through a list multiple times, ask yourself if there is some way to index it. You could use a `dict` that uses a cell as key and a list of rows where that cell appears as value. `collections.defaultdict` does some of the bookkeeping for you by creating items in the dict on first access. Your code could be

```
import csv
import collections

# index csv rows by column
csv_index = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open("word.csv", "rb") as tempfile:
    for row in csv.reader(tempfile):
        for col in row:
            csv_index[col].append(row)

# sample to check
sti = "this is not a very good string"
sss =  sti.split(" ")
print sss

# lookup words from sample and print
for word in sss:
    print word
    for row in csv_index[word]:
        print(row)
```

This outputs

```
['this', 'is', 'not', 'a', 'very', 'good', 'string']
this
is
not
a
['proud', 'of', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'a', '-0.03118']
['proud', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'a', '0.5']
very
good
string
```